# iphone application payment from website,Apple's payment policy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services, cocoa-touch, payment

I am developing a game application with majority of web content,but also have to provide support for iPhone. Here users have to first register on the server from the website,and based on their payment they are given membership type (gold,silver,etc) for the game. They can play the game on iPhone also,using registration ids to indicate user type.Each time on gameplay certain amount is deducted from their account. The iPhone version of game also keeps tab on amount remaining and prompts user to replenish on server.
   Payment is entirely on server side and only data is passed through iphone application.

Does this in anyways violates Apples rules?? Can it cause App rejection??

Answer (score 0):

I don't know 100% but it sounds like it might if not invalidate sail pretty close to what Apple sees as acceptable. Why don't you deal with all payments through a web-based site and simply allow registered users to access the game via iPhone. When a user runs out of time you could simply suspend the app and start up a web browser to access your site / renew game time.

Also (and I am not familiar with this) but in app purchases might be a good way to go?

all the best

Gary

Comment: Hello Gary,thanks for your prompt reply.Have read Apple's policy and was apprehensive thats why put up the question.Well,web-based site is precisely what i am planning for the game,payment and registration will be provided there itself.But I also wanted to provide mobile platform(iPhone,android)for playing game only and checking credit amount remaining from time to time.Already having payment system on website was hoping to do without InApp for simplicity. Still was not too clear with Apple's approval policy.. thanks ...tc ShanTrip

Comment: No problem at all, sorry I could not be more specific.